# How to wrap highlighted text with a span and place a div positioned relative to it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My end goal is for the user to be able to :

- select text from a paragraph
- wrap the text in a span
- place an action button / div at the end of the selection that they could click to take further action

Here is my code so far:

```
function Discussion(){       
    var $this = this;
    $(document).bind("mouseup",function(){
        $this.selectText($this);
    });
}
Discussion.prototype.selectText = function($this){
    var selection = $this.getSelectedText();
    if(selection.length > 3){
        console.log(selection);
        var spn = '<span class="selected">' + selection + '</span>';
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(selection, spn)); 
        //ERROR here; it says that it can't replace() on undefined $(this).html()
    }
}
Discussion.prototype.getSelectedText = function(){
    if(window.getSelection){
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    }
    else if(document.getSelection){
        return document.getSelection();
    }
    else if(document.selection){
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
}
```

As you might expect, so far I can get the text of the selection with `window.getSelection().toString()`. If I remove the `.toString()`, I get a `Selection` object. With this I can use `window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode` to get most of the information I need.

I also see that `Selection.anchorOffset` and `Selection.extentOffset` will give me the range of characters I've selected. Is there a way I can use this information to place the span?

I guess my questions would be:

- Why isn't this code wrapping the selection in divs?
- Will this fail with multiple instances of the same text?
- After wrapping the selection with a span or inline-block div or something, will I be able to get (and use) its position for positioning an additional button / div?

Phew, thanks for your time!

Edit: I added a JS fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/nn62G/

Comment: I'm not professional in Jquery. However, are you sure that this code is used commonly with Jquery?!

Comment: Hmm, it was my attempt at OOP JS code using jQuery to make things easier. Does it look funky?

Comment: Could you please include HTML and CSS part as well, probably encapsulated in jsfiddle? That will help. Rgds,

Comment: @AlexBell I've created a simple JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QDFZA/1/

Comment: here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nn62G/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by `getSelectedText` is a selection not an element in the DOM. That is why your cal to the `html` function is failing, selection has no such property.

You can do what you want as follows, set the part of the document you want to process as `contentEditable` for example a `<p>` or `<div>`. When you select within that area then you can get the HTML element using `document.activeElement`. If you select outside a `contentEdiatble` area then `activeElement` returns the `body` element. The `activeElement` you CAN process :

```
document.activeElement.innerHTML = 
    document.activeElement.innerHTML.replace (selection, spn);
```

However, if you make parts of your document editable other things happen which you may not want. More seriously, if the selected text occurs multiple times you cannot determine which one has actually been selected so this may not be a solution to your problem.

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wjAh3/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to post my js fiddle here with the solution for posterity. Thanks for all the help, everyone!

http://jsfiddle.net/prodikl/mP8KT/

```
function Discussion(){       
    var $this = this;
    $(document).bind("mouseup",function(){
        $this.selectText($this);
    });
}
Discussion.prototype.selectText = function($this){
    $("mark").contents().unwrap();
    $("mark").remove();
    var selection = $this.getSelection(); 
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var cssclass = $(selection.anchorNode.parentNode).attr("class");
    if(selection.toString().length > 2){
        $this.startPoint = selection.anchorOffset;
        $this.endPoint = selection.extentOffset;
        var newNode = document.createElement("mark");
        range.surroundContents(newNode);
        $("mark").attr('title', ' ');
        $("mark").tooltip({
            content : "<a class='content' href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>Here's a link.</a>"
        });
        $("mark").on('mouseleave',function(event){
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }).tooltip("open");
    }
}
Discussion.prototype.getSelection = function(){
    if(window.getSelection){
        return window.getSelection();
    }
    else if(document.getSelection){
        return document.getSelection();
    }
    else if(document.selection){
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
}
var discussion = new Discussion();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok well, a possible solution could be to find the element that contains the current selection and replace it's html something like:

```
// this get's you all the elements (including the top parent) that contain the selection
var existsInElements = $('*:contains("' + selection + '")');

// the exact element match is in the last one
var exactElement = existsInElements[existsInElements.length - 1];
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn62G/4/) that works.